# Phrase: 'cited after'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

I don't understand what's the meaning of "**cited after**" in books, when they cite a source,
e.g.,

> (cited after Manin 1997: 3)

Answer (score 1):

It means that the author didn't actually look the quote up himself (didn't actually read the source cited in "The Principles of Representative Government", in this case) but instead relied on another author to come up with the correct citation. It's a second-hand quote, if you will, and usually a no-go in serious academic writing (except, perhaps, in somy very exceptional circumstances, if you've cleared it with your academic advisor.)

Comment: +1 Any source you can cite (or cite after) for this information can be useful, too.

Comment: Most universities and colleges that I am aware of allow such "secondary citations" only when the original text could not be obtained despite strong efforts (which certainly includes inter-library loans). But hey, who's judging, I just wanted to answer the question.

Comment: I mean using that phrase "cited after" -- has it been mentioned anywhere, say in style manuals or similar guides?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, are you referring to the actual phrase "cited after"? Some style guides do use it, others prefer "Foo (as cited in Bar, 2000)" or "McKenzie (2006, cited in Lee and Fung, 2008)". It somehow smacks of the German "zitiert nach" which is used in German academic writing.

Comment: Obviously you didn't follow. Why "cited after"? How did that phrase come to be?

Comment: How am I supposed to know? I just answered the original question.