# What is the difference between "cited in" and "cited after"?

Tags: citation

What's the difference between "cited in" and "cited after"
e.g.

(cited in Hofstadter 1969: 10)
and
(cited after Manin 1997: 3)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148878/14666

Answer (score 0):

Cited in means that the citation is contained within a larger work. It is based on a containment metaphor.

Cited after means that the citation is preceded by something, to with it is a consequent.